# server 2008 .net framework 4 503 error

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, http-status-code-503

I just installed .net 4 on my server 2008 and I keep getting
Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

messages from any application I try to run as .net 4. The application pool keeps stopping. Event view shows: "The worker process failed to pre-load .Net Runtime version v4.0.30319."

Comment: Have you tried googling http://fooberry.com/2009/10/30/iis-7-net-4-0-beta-2-and-503-service-unavailableafter-beta-1/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/78466/iis-gives-503-after-updating-net-4-0-to-beta-2

Comment: yes. I didn't install the beta and I've registered .net 4 twice already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved. I uninstalled .net 4 and reinstalled using the "web platform installer". restarted and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same thing on a windows core 2008 R2 box.

Running 'oclist' showed that there were some missing windows features.
To install them, i needed to run the following commands:

```
ocsetup NetFx2-ServerCore-WOW64
ocsetup NetFx3-ServerCore-WOW64
```